# Animate a combined geometry along a path

Tags: wpf, geometry, animated

I have WPF/VB application that animates an ellipse geometry along a path using point animation. I used PointAnimationUsingPath and a Storyboard as per [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743217%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it works great.

I now want to show a number inside the ellipse. To do this I created a combined geometry and set my ellipse as geometry1. I then created a formattedtext(...).buildgeometry for my number and set that as geometry2. Like this:

```
Dim CarGeo AS New CombinedGeometry()
CarGeo.Geometry1 = New EllipseGeometry(StartPoint, 5, 5)
CarGeo.Geometry2 = New FormattedText(carIndex.ToString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, New Typeface("Veranda"), 7, Brushes.White).BuildGeometry(New Point(StartPoint.X - 4, StartPoint.Y - 4))
```

The resulting geometry is exactly what I wanted.

The problem is I don't seem to be able to animate this geometry along my path because unlike an ellipse there is no center property in a combined geometry to set the targeted property to on the StoryBoard.

```
' Create a PointAnimationgUsingPath to move the car along the animation path.
cpAnimation = New PointAnimationUsingPath
cpAnimation.PathGeometry = pgSectorPath(intSector)
cpAnimation.Duration = timDuration
' Set the animation to target the Center property of the EllipseGeometry
Storyboard.SetTargetName(cpAnimation, "CarGeo")
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(cpAnimation, New PropertyPath(EllipseGeometry.CenterProperty))
```

Is there I property in a combined geometry that I can use for the animation?
If not can I wrap the geometry in something else that can be animated?

I'm very new to WPF and have wasted way too much time searching for an answer to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the CombinedGeometry into a Path object, as in the MS example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx